# Submit operation failed validation

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, mvvm

I am working with silver light application with MVVM Concept and Enity framework and having some trouble in updating the values. Let me elaborate my problem. I am having three tables say A, B, and C where B has the foreign key relationship with A and C has foreign key relationship with B. I could able to save these tables with out any problem. I am using a view to bind the grid and able to retrieve values for editing but unable to update any changes to the data base.
While Update am getting this error **

> Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application  Code: 4004
> Category: ManagedRuntimeError        Message:
> System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException:
> Submit operation failed validation. Please inspect
> Entity.ValidationErrors for each entity in EntitiesInError for more
> information.    en
> System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Exception
> error)    en
> System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.SubmitOperation.Complete(OperationErrorStatus
> errorStatus)    en
> System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__3(Object
> )

**

here is the view model class..

```
public void Save(object obj)
    {   
            _currentCustomer.ModifiedBy = App.CurrentUser;
            _currentCustomer.ModifiedDateTime = System.DateTime.Now;

            foreach (BizFramework.Web.Model.Address address in AddressCollection.ToList())
            {
                string address1 = Convert.ToString(address.Address1);
                if (address1 != null && address1.Trim()!="")
                {                        
                    CVEReference = (from addref in _currentCustomer.CustomerVendorEmployeeReferences 
                                  where addref.CustomerID == _currentCustomer.CustomerID 
                                  select addref).SingleOrDefault();

                    BizFramework.Web.Model.Address addressExists = (from rec in CVEReference.Addresses
                                                                    where rec.AddressTypeID == address.AddressTypeID
                                                                    select rec).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (addressExists != null)
                    {
                        address.ModifiedBy = App.CurrentUser;
                        address.ModifiedDateTime = System.DateTime.Now;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        address.AddressGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
                        address.ApplicationOwner = App.CurrentUser;
                        address.CreatedBy = App.CurrentUser;
                        address.ModifiedBy = App.CurrentUser;
                        address.CreatedDateTime = System.DateTime.Now;
                        address.ModifiedDateTime = System.DateTime.Now;

                        CVEReference.Addresses.Add(address);
                    }
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    //_currentCustomer.Addresses.Remove(address);
                    AddressCollection.Remove(address);
                    //dcBusinessAccountingContext.Addresses.Remove(address);
                }
            }                         

        dcBusinessAccountingContext.SubmitChanges();
    }

//Setting Table A from the view like this

_currentCustomer = (from CustomerAddress in dcBusinessAccountingContext.Customers
                                    where CustomerAddress.CustomerID == AddrView.CustomerID
                                    select CustomerAddress).SingleOrDefault();
```

where _currentcustomer is the A's entity Object, CVEReference is the B's entity object, AddrView is the entityset of the Table View and addresscollection is the collection of C.

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Did you read the error message?  ***Please inspect Entity.ValidationErrors for each entity in EntitiesInError for more information.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error says that this is validation issue.
change `dcBusinessAccountingContext.SubmitChanges();` to

```
dcBusinessAccountingContext.SubmitChanges(SubmitCallback, null);
```

Then you can do some error checking:

```
private void SubmitCallback(SubmitOperation operation)
{
        if (operation.HasError)
        {
           //check "operation.EntitiesInError" for more details.
        }
}
```